# Lightning radio button NOT getting the correct value (or modifying it)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, radio-button, lightning-outlook

On the Lightning for Outlook, I do have a record creation button component. Clicking on it gets the custom record type selection. Based on what we choose(radio button), **force:createRecord** event fires.

Ltng.cmp

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.RTypeList}" var="rType"> 
   <span class="slds-radio">
        <input type="radio" aura:id = "radioId"  id="{!rType}" name="options" value="{!rType}" />
        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="{!rType}">
           <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
           <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!rType}</span>
        </label>
       </span>
  </aura:iteration>
```

NOTE: RTypeList contains all the record type labels(using controller class).

Cmp.Js

```
var rTypeLabel= document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').value;
    var action = component.get("c.getRTypeId");

    action.setParams({
        "rTypeLabel": rTypeLabel
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
            var RTID  = response.getReturnValue();
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": 'Account',
                "recordTypeId": RTID  
            });
            createRecordEvent.fire();

        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
           alert("ERROR! Please contact support!");
        }
     });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Controller.apxc

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id getRTypeId(String rTypeLabel){
    System.debug('From Class: ' +rTypeLabel);
    if(rTypeLabel!= ''){
        Id rtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();        
        return rtypeid ;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Every time I run this component on an LightningAPP (to preview), debug log returns me the correct record type label. But when I run this same component on the "Lightning for Outlook", I get the log as "**From Class: on**" thus throwing me the error. 
Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after spending few extra hours than usual, I was able to fix it. 
The problem with my code lies within the `document.querySelector`. As per my `<input type="radio"` implementation, I do not need **value**, rather I need to query **id**. Like this:

```
var rTypeLabel= document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').id
```

But hey, when I query 'value' instead of 'id', it worked well on Google Chrome(verified console) and I got the state as SUCCESS. But on the Internet Explorer and the Lightning For Outlook plugin, it didn't worked. So my trial-and-error with id worked on both. Hope someone who's stuck with this kind of issue find my post helpful.