# <input type="radio" returning ON with onclick function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, onclick, radio-button, lightning-for-outlook

To my previous **[Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207998/lightning-radio-button-not-getting-the-correct-value-or-modifying-it)**, I did some more debugging and ended up log with **OnClick value: on**

Good thing is, I have my LightningApp on the Internet Explorer which helped to get to the console logs(Chrome browser getting me the correct log value).

Aura.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedRecordType" type="String"/>
...
<aura:iteration items="{!v.RTypeList}" var="rType"> 
<span class="slds-radio">
    <input type="radio" aura:id="radioId"  
           id="{!rType}" name="options" value="{!rType}" 
           onclick="{!c.selectedRadio}"/>
    <label class="slds-radio__label" for="{!rType}">
       <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
       <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!rType}</span>
    </label>
   </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

Aura.Js

```
selectedRadio: function(component, event, helper){
    var temp = event.target.value;
    component.set('v.selectedRecordType',temp);
    console.log('OnClick value: ' +temp);
}
```

I am trying to set the value for **selectedRecordType** attribute, that way I can use it in other button which fires the `force:recordCreate` event.
But I am ended up with the log: **OnClick value: on**

I have also tried using: `event.getSource().getElement().value` but I always gets an runtime error:

> [Object doesn't support property or method 'getSource']

When I debug Lightning App via Google Chrome, on the console, I can see the selected radio button values as they get select. But why it is not working this way on Internet Explorer???? On IE, I can only get **OnClick value: on** each and every time, but what causing this to work on Chrome and not on IE???????

Comment: Any reason why you're not using lightning:radioGroup?

Comment: No reason. I have started implementing in this approach, so trying to finish it off.

Comment: Huh. It works in my dev org copied verbatim.

Comment: :( oh lord. That's what happened in my Chrome browser. I can see the onclick value picked from the selected radio button, but on IE, I cannot get it, thus Lightning for Outlook fails.

Comment: I've created [tag:lightning-for-outlook], since it seems specific to this feature.

Comment: Sounds good. My previous(linked) question would have more implementation I did.

Comment: @sfdcfox If I wanted to use lightning:radioGroup, how can I use it for list of records that are being extracted after the doInit action?

Comment: There's an example in the docs

Comment: Well, I tried it. I think it's getting me the values (I can see 8 radio buttons), but without the text next to the radio. And yes, clicking on any of then giving me log:  **OnClick value: on** still. damn